# How to reuse a cart button in another component

Tags: reactjs, button, react-hooks, components, react-context

Im new to React and trying to reuse a cart Button which I made for store, in Navbar and update it.
here is my Store component.
I tried to import All the involving components in Navbar as well and still no luck.
I tried as well useContext() and props but nothing worked. Im very confused right now

Appreciate any help.

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import TrackVisibility from "react-on-screen";
import { Row, Col, Button, Navbar, Modal } from "react-bootstrap";
import { productsArray } from "./productsStore";
import ProductCard from "./ProductCard";
import { CartContext } from "./CartContext";
import CartProduct from "./CartProduct";
import "./Store.css";



const Book = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
  const cart = useContext(CartContext);

{/*  const checkout = async () => {
    await fetch("http://localhost:4000/checkout", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ items: cart.items }),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.url) {
          window.location.assign(response.url); // Forwarding user to Stripe
        }
      });
  }; 
*/}

  const productCount = cart.items.reduce(
    (sum, product) => sum + product.quantity,
    0
  );

  return ( 
   
    <>
      <div
        className="app__store app__bg section__padding flex__center"
        id="booking"
      >
        <Navbar expand="sm" className="app__bg" variant="dark">
          <Navbar.Brand href="/book" className="headtext__cormorant">
           Book a Session{" "}
            <p className="p__opensans"></p>
          </Navbar.Brand>

####   This is the button im trying to reuse in Navbar  ###


          <Button
            className="custom__button"
            variant="success"
            onClick={handleShow}
          >
            Cart ({productCount} Items)
          </Button>


        </Navbar>
        <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
          <Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Title>Your Booking</Modal.Title>

          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            {productCount > 0 ? (
              <>
                <p>Items in your cart:</p>
                {cart.items.map((currentProduct, idx) => (
                  <CartProduct
                    key={idx}
                    id={currentProduct.id}
                    quantity={currentProduct.quantity}
                  >
                    {" "}
                  </CartProduct>
                ))}
                <h1>Total: {cart.getTotalCost().toFixed(2)}</h1>
                <button className="custom__button" onClick={()=> window.open("https://form.jotform.com/231252553810347")}>
                  Complete Your Order!
                </button>
              </>
            ) : (
              <h1>There are no itmes in your cart!</h1>
            )}
          </Modal.Body>
        </Modal>
      </div>
      <div className="app__bg app__wrapper section__padding">
        <Row xs={1} md={2} lg={4} className="g-4">
          {productsArray.map((product, idx) => (
            <Col align="center" key={idx}>
              <TrackVisibility partialVisibility>
                {({ isVisible }) => (
                  <div
                    className={
                      isVisible ? "animate__animated animate__flipInY" : ""
                    }
                  >
                    <ProductCard product={product} />
                  </div>
                )}
              </TrackVisibility>
            </Col>
          ))}
        </Row>
      </div>
    </>

  );
};

export default Book;
```

Answer (score 0):

so I found the issue! It was the CartProvider which wasnt including Navbar component and because of that the Button wasnt updating !
I wrapped the Navbar in CartProvider and now it works!

```js
<CartProvider>
    <Navbar />
    <Header />
    <AboutUs />
    <Massage />
    <Yoga />
    <Energy />
    <Event />
    <Fire />
    <Music />
    <Intro />
      <Container>
        {/* <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="success" element={<Success />} />
            <Route path="cancel" element={<Cancel />} />
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter> */}
      </Container>
      <Store></Store>
    </CartProvider>
    <Footer />
    </>
```